# Disable Remote Debugging in VS2013?

Tags: remote, debug, visual-studio-2013

I recently opened up VS2013 to a project that I have been working on for a while to find that when I try and debug it, it fails and mentions something about a Remote Debugger not running on a remote machine. This confused me as I have only ever worked on this project on this machine and I never even knew about Remote Debugging before now. Ctrl-F5 still works but F5 brings up the error.

I've searched around but I have found no answers. Where can I disable Remote Debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely has nothing to do with Remote Debugging.  Just open your project properties and select the "Debug" tab (in Web Applications open the "Web" tab).  Make sure an appropriate debugger is selected.  You don't mention what kind of project you're working on, so its tough to say what the appropriate action should be.

Comment: I had a look in my project settings and I can see that debugging on a remote server is already unticked. Even more confusing. http://imgur.com/ffgOlwS.png

Comment: Can you copy the exact text of the error message (Ctrl + C when the dialog is up) into your original question.

Comment: I just messed around with some settings and it turns out that changing the target CPU architecture fron 'Any' to 'x86' made it work again. Any ideas why that is?

Comment: You can setup specific debugging options for each platform, can you see any differences when you change the combo box on that screen?

Comment: http://imgur.com/0HjtdB4 Here is the exact message I'm getting, as requested.

Comment: Idea: Maybe my VS2013 only supports x86 debugging and it thinks that when I want to debug in x64 it thinks I have another machine which can run it? Not sure if any of that makes sense.